# Is it possible to use encrypted properties in karate?

Tags: karate

I have an application.properties file with an encrypted property:

```
test.username='testUser'
test.password=ENC(3ncryp73dp@$$w0rd)
```

And I want to use the decrypted value in a feature file, kind of like:

```
Feature: Login

Scenario: Test login at myurl.com
Given url 'myurl.com/login'
And param username = testUsername
And param password = testPassword
When method GET
[etc]
```

Normally Spring-boot handles decrypting those properties and I can just use

```
@Value(${test.username})
protected String testUsername;
```

in my step definitions class to get a property from the `application.properties` file.

How can I do that with Karate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for this. My suggestion is use [Java interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java). You may be even able to tap into the code that Spring Boot uses if you add that to the classpath / maven dependencies. So you can end up with something like this:

```
And param username = MyUtil.decode(testUserName)
And param password = MyUtil.decode(testPassword)
```